# Error executing DDL postgres Java spring boot API

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I'm developing a request API in java spring boot, I developed my post but when testing it returns the 400 bad request error and the following error in the terminal

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table restaurant_orders (id uuid not null, address varchar(25) not null, block varchar(5), customer_name varchar(11) not null, door_number varchar(10) not null, order varchar(30) not null, phone_number varchar(15) not null, price float4 not null, registration_date timestamp(6) not null, primary key (id))" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:587) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:532) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:307) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:79) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:225) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:284) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1429) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:140) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:415) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1425) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[spring-orm-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1130) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:905) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
    at com.api.order_control.OrderControlApplication.main(OrderControlApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "order"
  Position: 169
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2676) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2366) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:496) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:413) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:333) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:319) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:295) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:290) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
```

I saw in some searches that the name "order" could be causing a problem in the database, so I changed it to "orders_restaurant" and I still have the same problem

model

```
package com.api.order_control.models;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "restaurant_orders")
public class OrderModel implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 11)
    private String customerName;
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 15)
    private String phoneNumber;
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 25)
    private String address;
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String doorNumber;
    @Column(nullable = true, length = 5)
    private String block;
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 30)
    private String order;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Float price;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime registrationDate;

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getDoorNumber() {
        return doorNumber;
    }

    public void setDoorNumber(String doorNumber) {
        this.doorNumber = doorNumber;
    }

    public String getBlock() {
        return block;
    }

    public void setBlock(String block) {
        this.block = block;
    }

    public String getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(String order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    public Float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getRegistrationDate() {
        return registrationDate;
    }

    public void setRegistrationDate(LocalDateTime registrationDate) {
        this.registrationDate = registrationDate;
    }
}
```

controller

```
package com.api.order_control.controllers;


import com.api.order_control.dtos.OrderDto;
import com.api.order_control.models.OrderModel;
import com.api.order_control.services.OrderService;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RequestMapping("/order")
public class OrderController {

    final OrderService orderService;

    public OrderController(OrderService orderService) {
        this.orderService = orderService;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Object> saveOrder(@RequestBody @Valid OrderDto orderDto) {
        var orderModel = new OrderModel();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(orderDto, orderModel);
        orderModel.setRegistrationDate(LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC")));
        orderModel.setPrice(70.8f);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(orderService.save(orderModel));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack trace says that you have a problem in generated sql script at pos. 169. `order` is a keyword in sql, don't use it as a property name. Meanwhile, your table can have name `orders` without any problem

Comment: I did that and the error stopped appearing in the console, but I still get a bad request in my postman

Comment: If you receive 400, but no stack trace in std out, then your exception handled by http servlet container. Put the break point on the second line of your `saveOrder` method an use 'step into' feature in your IDE to see the trace of calls and notice the line where execution proceeds to exception handler

Comment: A question that maybe you can help me with... If you see my post method in a controller, you'll notice  "orderModel.setPrice(70.8f);". I am sending an already established price for this column in my database, but I would like to send this directly from the body sent by my user without the dto. Can you tell me how I can do this in this syntax?

Comment: Doesn't `BeanUtils.copyProperties` do this?

Comment: BeanUtils.copyProperties does this with blanks that are in dto, my price is not, so I would like to set this directly in my controlle as I am doing, but instead of sending a value, I receive the user's value

Comment: If you want to get the price from client side and don't want for some reason put it inside request body, another viable option would be to use @RequestParam